# title: Avoid examination of rows in select statement when using join tables with many to many relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a curious situation here:

I want to find every item in table a that contains certain tag_names. 
A select statement like „Where […] in("x"  ‚"y")":

would frankly function as „or“ and examine all rows of table a and b that contain „x“ and „y“.
example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/483fb/2/0

This show only one result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/483fb/4

as you can see here 10 rows where examined

Is there a way to only examine the rows that contain „x“ and „y“
a „and“ statement would result in an „impossible where"

Thanks for every effort!

Comment: You should duplicate the table data here at the very least, external links are unreliable.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92505/1 adds two indexes, shows an improved query plan; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f91942/1 adds two indexes and shows an alternate query, joining the tag-related tables twice, so that we never bother looking at items not matching whichever tag is checked first (and "first" is decided by the optimizer, not by the order in the query on inner joins).

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael - sqlbot! Solved the problem !